# Python конвертировать xml в json и добавить в json-объекты новые поля

Tags: python, json, xml

Мне нужно распарсить массив таких записей на питоне, конвертировать их в JSON и в каждый JSON-объект добавить несколько полей.

```
<vpuStatusReply>
<vpu>
<vpuID value="795174117"/>
<vpuNumber value="062202"/>
<vpuStateID value="314"/>
<vpuState value="Согласован"/>
<vpuNeedForECP value="0"/>
<vpuLastOper value="10.06.2018 07:19:05"/>
<docPrice value="0"/>
</vpu>
<vpu>
<vpuID value="795174757"/>
<vpuNumber value="062203"/>
<vpuStateID value="314"/>
<vpuState value="Согласован"/>
<vpuNeedForECP value="0"/>
<vpuLastOper value="10.06.2018 07:23:32"/>
<docPrice value="0"/>
</vpu>
<vpu>
```

Написал такой код:

```
import json
import untangle

""" with open("data.xml") as f:
    printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent = 4)
    xml = f.read()
    printer.pprint(json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xml)))
    obj = untangle.parse(xml)
    print(obj.vpuStatusReply.vpu[0].vpuID['value']) """

class Marshaler:
    def marshal_xml(self, xml_data):
        parsed = untangle.parse(xml_data)
        json_array = []
        for entry in parsed.vpuStatusReply.vpu:
            self.parse_entry(entry)

    def parse_entry(self, entry):
        json_data = {}
        print(entry.keys())


with open("vpu.txt") as f:
    xml = f.read()
    marshaler = Marshaler()
    marshaler.marshal_xml(xml)
```

Хочу пройти по массиву `obj.vpuStatusReply.vpu`, конвертировать каждый xml-элемент массива в json и добавить к нему нужные поля. Как это можно сделать?

Предполагаю, что в методе parse_entry мне нужно пройти по всем полям, получить значения и из этих данных создать JSON. Но я не знаю, как это реализуется на питоне.

Далее, все такие JSON-объекты надо добавить в массив и массив сконвертировать в JSON. Подскажите, что для этого есть в питоне.

Дополнил метод parse_entry:

```
def parse_entry(self, entry):
    json_data = {}
    json_data['creatorId'] = 'ETRANTEST'
    json_data['sysId'] = 0
    json_data['type'] = 'document'
    json_data['documentType'] = 'ETRANvpuState'
    json_data['vpuID'] = entry.vpuID['value']
    json_data['vpuNumber'] = entry.vpuNumber['value']
    json_data['vpuStateID'] = entry.vpuStateID['value']
    json_data['vpuState'] = entry.vpuState['value']
    json_data['vpuNeedForECP'] = entry.vpuNeedForECP['value']
    json_data['vpuLastOper'] = entry.vpuLastOper['value']
    json_data['docPrice'] = entry.docPrice['docPrice']
    return json_data
```

Хочу заменить такое добавление полей одним циклом по ключам. А также нужно в sysId записывать порядковый номер записи в массиве vpu. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте воспользоваться модулем `xmltodict`:

```
import xmltodict  # pip install xmltodict

d = xmltodict.parse(xml)
```

результат:

```
In [17]: d['vpuStatusReply']
Out[17]:
OrderedDict([('vpu',
              [OrderedDict([('vpuID', OrderedDict([('@value', '795174117')])),
                            ('vpuNumber', OrderedDict([('@value', '062202')])),
                            ('vpuStateID', OrderedDict([('@value', '314')])),
                            ('vpuState',
                             OrderedDict([('@value', 'Согласован')])),
                            ('vpuNeedForECP', OrderedDict([('@value', '0')])),
                            ('vpuLastOper',
                             OrderedDict([('@value', '10.06.2018 07:19:05')])),
                            ('docPrice', OrderedDict([('@value', '0')]))]),
               OrderedDict([('vpuID', OrderedDict([('@value', '795174757')])),
                            ('vpuNumber', OrderedDict([('@value', '062203')])),
                            ('vpuStateID', OrderedDict([('@value', '314')])),
                            ('vpuState',
                             OrderedDict([('@value', 'Согласован')])),
                            ('vpuNeedForECP', OrderedDict([('@value', '0')])),
                            ('vpuLastOper',
                             OrderedDict([('@value', '10.06.2018 07:23:32')])),
                            ('docPrice', OrderedDict([('@value', '0')]))])])])
```

после этого можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

add_info = {
   'creatorId':'ETRANTEST',
   'sysId':0,
   'type':'document',
   'documentType':'ETRANvpuState'}

df = (pd.io.json.json_normalize(d['vpuStatusReply']['vpu'])
        .rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace('.@value',''))
        .assign(**add_info))
```

результат в виде Pandas DataFrame:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
       vpuID vpuNumber vpuStateID    vpuState vpuNeedForECP          vpuLastOper docPrice  creatorId  sysId      type   documentType
0  795174117    062202        314  Согласован             0  10.06.2018 07:19:05        0  ETRANTEST      0  document  ETRANvpuState
1  795174757    062203        314  Согласован             0  10.06.2018 07:23:32        0  ETRANTEST      0  document  ETRANvpuState
```

DataFrame можно легко представить в виде списка записей `list of dictionaries`:

```
In [34]: df.to_dict('r')
Out[34]:
[{'vpuID': '795174117',
  'vpuNumber': '062202',
  'vpuStateID': '314',
  'vpuState': 'Согласован',
  'vpuNeedForECP': '0',
  'vpuLastOper': '10.06.2018 07:19:05',
  'docPrice': '0',
  'creatorId': 'ETRANTEST',
  'sysId': 0,
  'type': 'document',
  'documentType': 'ETRANvpuState'},
 {'vpuID': '795174757',
  'vpuNumber': '062203',
  'vpuStateID': '314',
  'vpuState': 'Согласован',
  'vpuNeedForECP': '0',
  'vpuLastOper': '10.06.2018 07:23:32',
  'docPrice': '0',
  'creatorId': 'ETRANTEST',
  'sysId': 0,
  'type': 'document',
  'documentType': 'ETRANvpuState'}]
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что это не то. Конвенции по именованию атрибутов @value неудобны. Потом этот JSON надо сохранять в MongoDB. Подойдет ли формат xmltodict для хранения данных в монге?

Comment: @typemoon, об этом стоило сказать в вопросе, а не в комментариях (что надо преобразовать XML в структуру, которую легко импортировать в MongoDB). Я добавил вариант преобразования получившегося словаря в формат понятный MongoDB ...

Comment: а как можно значению поля sysId присвоить порядковый номер записи?

Comment: @typemoon, задайте отдельный SO вопрос... ;)